# Can an artificer cast spells with a free hand and a shield without using an object interaction action?

Tags: dnd-5e, spell-components, artificer

Suppose a level 1 artificer has a hand free and the other wielding a shield.

Can the artificer cast spells without using up their object interaction action?

For most spellcasters, a free hand is enough to cast spells, with no object interaction action required:

> **Material (M):**
>   [...]  A spellcaster must have a hand free to access a spell's material components -- or to hold a spellcasting focus -- but it can be the same hand that he or she uses to perform somatic components.

However, the Artificer has a special requirement for their spells:

> You produce your artificer spell effects through your tools. You must have a spellcasting focus – specifically thieves’ tools or some kind of artisan’s tool – in hand when you cast any spell with this Spellcasting feature.

Does this mean the artificer have to spend an object interaction action to wield the tool before he can cast a spell? Or, can the artificer access the tool as part of the spell?

Comment: The part you quote about material components does not actually say (nor does it imply) that an object interaction is not necessary for a "classic" spellcaster.

Comment: @Szega more details are found here: [Can you cast spells with a Somatic component if you're holding a two-handed weapon?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/51994/can-you-cast-spells-with-a-somatic-component-if-youre-holding-a-two-handed-weap)

Comment: Nope, they cannot be found there. That question does not concern itself with material components, only the somatic ones.

Comment: @Medix2 I'm asking if the artificer can cast spells with a free hand and a shield without using an object interaction action.

Comment: Related questions about the action-economy of spell-casting foci/components: "[Does a wizard need to hold a component pouch or focus in one hand in order for it to work?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/80271)", "[Must a component pouch/focus be “out” to be handled, or can I keep it in my pocket?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/157057), and "[If a reaction spell has material components, do I already need to be holding them to cast it?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/127312)". These (somewhat) establish that accessing foci/components is included in the casting time.

Comment: @Szega The above pool of questions might be helpful towards answering your first comment

Comment: It took me a couple of reads, but I understand this question now. Because that artificer quote seems to imply that all of your spells effectively now have a M component, even if they normally don't, do you need to actually be holding the tools already, or can you access it with a "free hand", as per normal spellcasting focus rules? I think this is a good question, +1

Comment: @NathanS Yeah it took me a bit as well, hence why I think any answers should consider whether or not the spell having a material component matters

Comment: Another related question: [Do all 2019 UA Artificer spells have a de facto material component?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/152611/do-all-2019-ua-artificer-spells-have-a-de-facto-material-component)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Artificer spellcasting goes on to say:

> After you gain the Infuse Item feature at 2nd level, you can also use any item bearing one of your infusions as a spellcasting focus.

Therefore, starting with the second level, if you infuse your shield or armor with Enhanced Defense, you would no longer need to wield your tools as a focus.

At first level, you still need to keep a hand on your tools, which is your only possible focus for satisfying material component requirements at that first level.